# Should function's parameters be passed by reference frequently?

Tags: c++, reference

Is passing argument by reference/using pointer better for overall performance of program, than passing it normally?

From the logic POV it's because there are no copies of already stored variables, but is it really?

I know, that passing every argument by reference could be harmful, but I am refering to situations, where there's even simple variable passed, that is not used later in overall code, so its change wouldn't even affect anything.

I was wondering, because I've noticed that a lot of fellow programmers use that in their code.

I just want to know, I realize, that such tweaks won't speed up program much, but that's for my conciousness about the code.

Comment: Before making (possibly sweeping) changes to your code: profile before, profile after.  The general guidance on my project is to use `const&` parameters for non-built-in types which are not sink parameters.  For sink parameters that are non-built-in types, use either `&&` or pass-by-(elided?)-copy.  Avoid out parameters (i.e., prefer return values).  Avoid mutating reference-parameters (i.e., prefer return values).  Do not pass by `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` UNLESS passing ownership (otherwise pass by `const&`, or `const*` if nullptr is okay).  That's a quick summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > I know, that passing every argument by reference could be harmful...

Using a const reference will prevent the altering of the object you pass, so it's safe.

> > Is passing argument by reference/using pointer better for overall performance of program, than passing it normally?
> >
> > From the logic POV it's because there are no copies of already stored variables, but is it really?

Your question applies to passing variables to use its values but not change them:

In the case of, for instace:

```
void test(const int& value);
```

Call

```
int i;
test(i);
```

The differences in performance and/or space are near to none, for primitive types, you need not to bother with this.

But if you have complex type objects their size ceases to be negligible, their size is almost always bigger than the size of a pointer and copying them might result in non negligible performance loss, in this case it's better to pass by reference, you are passing the address of that variable and this avoids unnecessary copies.

```
class Complex{
//data members inside
};

void test(const Complex& c){
    complex c;
    test(c);
}
```

Call

```
Complex c;
test(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is passing argument by reference/using pointer better for overall performance of program, than passing it normally?

It depends. In some cases it is better than passing by value, in some other cases it is worse, and in rest of the cases it doesn't matter. If you want to know whether passing a value or a reference is faster in some particular case, you need to measure.

> From the logic POV it is, because there are no copies of already stored

On the other hand, you are now not only copying a reference, but also indirecting through it to access the object.

Rule of thumb: In case you are passing an argument without intention of storing a copy for later, use a reference unless the type is trivially copyable and the size of a pointer or smaller. If you write a template and type could be either, then assume it is slow to copy and use a reference.